# How can I emit comments in a YAML document using Psych?

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

I want to generate a YAML document with some comments between sequence elements but I can't really figure out how to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: Pretty sure that this is not (directly) possible. But not sure enough to make it an answer. A workaround would be to somehow flag your sequence elements and post-process the YAML string to insert/convert the comments.

Comment: Please, see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217785/adding-comment-to-yaml-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can’t emit YAML documents containing comments with Psych. Psych basically dumps a Hash, and you can’t have comments in a Hash either.