# Adding comment to YAML programmatically

Tags: ruby, parsing, yaml

Given the simple YAML file for localisation:

```
root:
  label: 'Test'
  account: 'Account'
  add: 'Add'
  local_folder: 'Local folder'
  remote_folder: 'Remote folder'
  status: 'Status'
    subkey: 'Some value'
```

How can I add a comment to the end of line for some key programmatically in Ruby?
I need to get something like:

```
root:
  label: 'Test'
  account: 'Account'
  add: 'Add'
  local_folder: 'Local folder' #Test comment
  remote_folder: 'Remote folder'
  status: 'Status'
    subkey: 'Some value' #Test comment
```

Are there any other ways (may be using Linux sed) to accomplish this? 
My reason is to prepare the YAML file for further processing. (comments will act as labels for external tool to identify keys).

Comment: You can't. The contents of a YAML file is the serialized representation of an object and Ruby has no comment object, especially one that represents a comment associated with a hash key/value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'yaml'

str = <<-eol
root:
  label: 'Test'
  account: 'Account'
  add: 'Add'
  local_folder: 'Local folder'
  remote_folder: 'Remote folder'
  status: 'Status'
  subkey: 'Some value'
eol

h = YAML.load(str)
h["root"]["local_folder"] = h["root"]["local_folder"] + " !Test comment"
h["root"]["subkey"] = h["root"]["subkey"] + " !Test comment"

puts h.to_yaml 

# >> ---
# >> root:
# >>   label: Test
# >>   account: Account
# >>   add: Add
# >>   local_folder: Local folder !Test comment
# >>   remote_folder: Remote folder
# >>   status: Status
# >>   subkey: Some value !Test comment
```

***EDIT***

more programmatically:

```
require 'yaml'

str = <<-eol
root:
  label: 'Test'
  account: 'Account'
  add: 'Add'
  local_folder: 'Local folder'
  remote_folder: 'Remote folder'
  status: 'Status'
  subkey: 'Some value'
eol

h = YAML.load(str)
%w(local_folder subkey).each {|i| h["root"][i] = h["root"][i] + " !Test comment" }

puts h.to_yaml 

# >> ---
# >> root:
# >>   label: Test
# >>   account: Account
# >>   add: Add
# >>   local_folder: Local folder !Test comment
# >>   remote_folder: Remote folder
# >>   status: Status
# >>   subkey: Some value !Test comment
```

Comment: OMG, good point, thanks. But the reason here is that #Test comment is the actual value of a key, not just simple comment.

Comment: @crible is the solution ok with you? As I am not finding a way to print yaml as you asked.

Comment: yes, that is acceptable solution, I suppose I can then post process !Test comment values using command line sed tool. Thanks, looks like a working solution.