# Ruby YAML/Psych dump custom comments

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have various lang files in yaml. Every time I update one file, I want to track all the new keys, write them with the original text in all the other lang files, but delimited with `### NEW` and `### END`.
The translator will then periodically fetch them and update.
Example:

```
# it.yml
a: A
b: B
some:
  new: Key

# en.yml
a: A
b: B
```

After I run the program, `en.yml` should be:

```
a: A
b: B
### NEW
some:
  new: Key
### END
```

I've already done most of the work, updated the `en` object and tagged the new key in a custom object, but I cannot understand how to tell Psych to print out `### NEW` and `### END`.

Any help will be appreciated!

You can find the code here: https://gist.github.com/Iazel/4f5c9fcd9b33c3ea994c

---

**EDIT:**
After *A LOT* of searching, seems that `libyaml` doesn't support comments, hence I don't think is possible what I want to do... Not without extending `libyaml` at least.

Comment: Looks like [this has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889044/how-can-i-emit-comments-in-a-yaml-document-using-psych), looks like you may be stuck doing this as a post-processing step yourself.

Comment: That's not what I need, still I'm pretty sure it's doable if I can understand exactly how Psych create the final output... I'll the code so fare, maybe will help